# dimple.js/d3.js: How to toggle series

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, dimple.js

I have the code below that renders two series on a chart as well as the legends.  What i would like to do is when the respective legend item is clicked, i want to hide/unhide the relevant series line.  I am not sure how to do this.  I have seen this sample: http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_interactive_legends.  But i don't think it applies here since that example uses a single series, where as i am plotting two distinct lines.

Anyone know how i can solve?  Can i retrieve the series line based on which legend item is clicked?

```
<div id="chart1">
    <script>
        var svg1 = dimple.newSvg("#chart1", 600, 500);
        var data1 = [[{x: '01/31/1998', y: 100.0}, {x: '02/28/1998', y: 110.0}, {x: '03/31/1998', y: 120.0}, {x: '04/30/1998', y: 130.0}],
                    [{x: '01/31/1998', y: 120.0}, {x: '02/28/1998', y: 130.0}, {x: '03/31/1998', y: 140.0}, {x: '04/30/1998', y: 150.0}]]

        var chart1 = new dimple.chart(svg1);
        chart1.setBounds(70, 30, 400, 300)
        var xAxis = chart1.addTimeAxis("x", "x", "%m/%d/%Y", "%b %y");
        xAxis.title="Date"
        var yAxis = chart1.addMeasureAxis("y", "y");
        yAxis.title = "Price"

        s1 = chart1.addSeries("Series1", dimple.plot.line, [xAxis, yAxis]);
        s1.data = data1[0]
        s2 = chart1.addSeries("Series2", dimple.plot.line, [xAxis, yAxis]);
        s2.data = data1[1]
        myLegend1 = chart1.addLegend(510, 100,60, 200, "Right");
        chart1.draw();
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually slightly simpler than the case in the example because you don't need to worry about filtering.  Instead you can just create a dictionary and find the relevant dataset that way:

```
    var svg1 = dimple.newSvg("#chart1", 600, 500);
    var data1 = [[{x: '01/31/1998', y: 100.0}, {x: '02/28/1998', y: 110.0}, {x: '03/31/1998', y: 120.0}, {x: '04/30/1998', y: 130.0}],
                [{x: '01/31/1998', y: 120.0}, {x: '02/28/1998', y: 130.0}, {x: '03/31/1998', y: 140.0}, {x: '04/30/1998', y: 150.0}]]

    var chart1 = new dimple.chart(svg1);
    chart1.setBounds(70, 30, 400, 300)
    var xAxis = chart1.addTimeAxis("x", "x", "%m/%d/%Y", "%b %y");
    xAxis.title="Date"
    var yAxis = chart1.addMeasureAxis("y", "y");
    yAxis.title = "Price"
    var seriesDict = {};

    s1 = chart1.addSeries("Series1", dimple.plot.line, [xAxis, yAxis]);
    s1.data = data1[0]
    seriesDict["Series1"] = { data: data1[0], series: s1, visible: true };

    s2 = chart1.addSeries("Series2", dimple.plot.line, [xAxis, yAxis]);
    s2.data = data1[1]
    seriesDict["Series2"] = { data: data1[1], series: s2, visible: true };

    myLegend1 = chart1.addLegend(510, 100,60, 200, "Right");

    chart1.draw();

    chart1.legends = [];

    myLegend1.shapes.selectAll("rect")
      // Add a click event to each rectangle
      .on("click", function (e) {
        var meta = seriesDict[e.aggField[0]];
        if (seriesDict[e.aggField[0]].visible) {
            meta.series.data = [];
            d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.2);
            seriesDict[e.aggField[0]].visible = false;
        } else {
            meta.series.data = meta.data;         
            d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);     
            seriesDict[e.aggField[0]].visible = true;
        }
        chart1.draw(1000);
    });
```

http://jsbin.com/zadic/2/edit?js,output

Comment: hmmm..when i try to do this with some 'real' data, i get an exception which prevents the series line from being toggled:
[code]Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined dimple.v2.1.0.min.js:2(anonymous function) dimple.v2.1.0.min.js:2b._getOrderedList dimple.v2.1.0.min.js:2b._getSeriesOrder dimple.v2.1.0.min.js:2b.plot.line.draw dimple.v2.1.0.min.js:2(anonymous function) dimple.v2.1.0.min.js:1draw dimple.v2.1.0.min.js:1(anonymous function) 100:114(anonymous function)[/code]

Comment: Looks like the problem might be in: http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.0.min.js.   After referencing instead: http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.0.0.min.js, it works fine